# Magento1.9 : SSH command for apply catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I have 50k products in my magento store and whenever I try to apply catalog price rules it goes to 504 gateway timeout error, and I don't get is the process complete or not.

Is there any SSH command to apply catalog price rule in magento1.9?

Or any other way to apply catalog price rules?

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of solving in magento , try to solve with Nginx, Please check below link to find solution regarding 504 error  :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002268/prevent-nginx-504-gateway-timeout-using-php-set-time-limit